# How to convert JSON Object to Python List

Tags: python, json

I have this json object and i am trying to make it into a python list but i am getting some characters along that i don't need

```
import json

data = {
  "products": [
    {
      "product_cp": 100.0,  
      "product_sp": 120.0, 
      "product_name": "coke", 
    }, 
    {
      "product_cp": 100.5, 
      "product_sp": 120.0, 
      "product_name": "fanta", 
    }, 
    {
      "product_cp": 70.5,  
      "product_sp": 100.5, 
      "product_name": "pepsi", 
    }
  ]
}
data = json.dumps(data)
print(data)
print('\v')
data = json.loads(data)
data_list = list(data['products'])
```

when i do:

```
    print(data_list)
```

i get:

```
[{u'product_cp': 100.0, u'product_sp': 120.0, u'product_name': u'coke'},{u'product_cp': 100.5, u'product_sp': 120.0, u'product_name': u'fanta'}, {u'product_cp': 70.5, u'product_sp': 100.5, u'product_name': u'pepsi'}]
```

please how i do i make it so that {,[,},] an 'u characters doesn't show up?

Comment: What output do you want? The json is a list of products. For each product, there is a dictionary of attributes.

For example, the first product has an attribute "product_cp" which equals 100, an attribute "product_sp" which equals 120, and a "product_name" which equals "coke".

Right now, you are outputting a list of these dictionaries.

Comment: `please how i do i make it so that a 'u' characters doesn't show up?`
The 'u' character stands for 'unicode', it just denotes that the string is encoded in unicode and not ASCII

Comment: i want it to be like this:

['product_cp 100.0 product_sp 120.0 product_name coke', 'product_cp 100.5 product_sp 120.0 product_name fanta', 'product_cp 70.5 product_sp 100.5 product_name pepsi'] @Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

To print individual product details without the syntactical overhead({,[,],}) you can use a nested loop:

```
for product in data["products"]:
    for info in product:
        print("%s: %s" % (info, product[info]))
    print()
```

The output is:

```
product_cp: 100.0
product_sp: 120.0
product_name: coke

product_cp: 100.5
product_sp: 120.0
product_name: fanta

product_cp: 70.5
product_sp: 100.5
product_name: pepsi
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code under python 3.6, i am a python rookie as well.

```
jsonobject = json.dumps(data)
jsonobjectToString = json.loads(jsonobject)
for level1 in jsonobjectToString["products"]:
     str = level1["product_cp"],level1["product_sp"],level1["product_name"]
     resultresp.append(str)
print(resultresp)
===================
[(100.0, 120.0, 'coke'), (100.5, 120.0, 'fanta'), (70.5, 100.5, 'pepsi')]
```